# How to rewrite kinetic mass balance to get to proper SI units?

Tags: kinetics, concentration, units, equation-of-state, rate-equation

Suppose from kinetic mass balance I get the following differential equation of the molarity substances $A$,$B$, and $C$ in a reactor, with molar in- or outflow rate $\phi$, and rate constant $k$:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[C] 
= k[A]^2[B]^3 + \phi{C_{\mathrm{in}}} - \phi{C_{\mathrm{out}}}
$$

Where the dimensions convert to:

$$
[\pu{mol L-1 s-1}] 
= [\pu{s-1}] [\pu{mol5 L-5}] + [\pu{mol s-1}] - [\pu{mol s-1}]
$$

Which can be simplified by adding the flow rate terms to:

$$
[\pu{mol L-1 s-1}] 
= [\pu{s-1}] [\pu{mol5 L-5}] \pm [\pu{mol s-1}]
$$

By cancelling similar terms mole,seconds on both sides to:

$$[\pu{L-1}] = [\pu{mol4 L-5}] \pm 1$$

This seems that something is off about the rate constant, but also that there is no $\pu{L-1}$ term in the molar flow rate.

I don't expect exact answers to this, but could someone point me the right way, or send some clear explanation on either reaction rate constants or on kinetic mass balances? It seems I cannot find clear explanations, not even in textbooks.

Comment: Consider [Formatting of chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) by using mhchem MathJax package, available in CH SE by default, involving MJ syntax \ce{} and \pu{}  

E.g. write `$\ce{H2SO4}$` or `$\ce{a A <=> p P}$` or `$\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$`  to get $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{a A <=> p P}$ or $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ (all eventually with double dollars in the display mode like $$\ce{H2SO4}$$. // E.g. typographic rules say unit symbols are never in italic.

Comment: Okay will do, but do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: I know nothing about this, but looking at the dimensions you firstly seemed to have used for concentration $mol    L^{-1}$ on the LHS and simply $mol$ on the RHS, fixing that solves your second problem, and secondly by dimensionality arguments your assertion that the dimensions for k are $s^{-1}$ **must** be wrong. But don't ask me how to justify what the correct dimensions must be ($mol^{-4} L^4$).

Comment: Yes the units of *k* should be mol$^{-4}$L$^4$

Comment: @IanBush I do not understand what you mean, the concentration is the same on both sides, except that on the LHS it is the derivative, so it is over time.

Comment: @Andrew but that is not a possible dimension for $k$ right? The general formula for the dimension of $k$ is $[mol^{1-n}s^{-1}]$ which would translate for a reaction of $n=5$ (because sum of degrees $2+3=5$) to $[mol^{-4}s^{-1}]$. How would you explain this?

Comment: Sorry forgot the s-1. I was intending to say that you needed to add those units to the s-1 that you already had

Comment: Purpose of comments is not providing answers. There are 2 simple rules for dimensions in equations: Every additive/subtractive term on both eq. sides must have the same dimension. Arguments of elementary functions must be dimensionless.Otherwise, something is wrong.

Comment: It seems I took the general formula for $k$ wrong. The general formula is $[\pu{mol^{1-n}L^{n-1} t-1}]$ so indeed the $k$ can be $[\pu{mol-4L4t-1}]$. The flow rate would have to be divided by a volume $V$ to get to the same dimension.